# Commutative diagram using TeX Writer

Tags: packages, tikz-styles, ipad, commutative-diagrams

I bought an ipad app TeX writer and I am wondering if I can draw a commutative diagram.

It includes the packages

- amslatex
- revtex4-1
- IEEEtran
- babel
- cyrillic
- graphicx
- color
- xcolr
- geometry
- algorithm2e
- listings.

I could draw commutative diagram using a package amscd but  it does not produce commutative diagram with a diagonal arrow. Is there any package that I can use on TeX Writer with which I can draw a commutative diagram with a diagonal arrow.

It seems that one can add other packages and I tried but it did not work for me.

(I am not familiar those technical language.)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Comment: Adding packages is definitely possible - I've added the entirety of TeX Live.  The difficulties will be that TeX Writer doesn't use the eTeX extensions so any package that requires them won't work, and there are still some issues with transparency.  I'll have an experiment with what I have (using that app) and see what works.

Comment: @AndrewStacey Care to report back on this?

Comment: @AndrewStacey Any update?

Comment: @AndrewStacey If TeXWriter still hasn't e-TeX support, it's probably better to say so in order to push out the question from the unanswered list.

Comment: @AndrewStacey Can you check whether Xy-pic works with TeXWriter?

Comment: @egreg Just tried it and it does work.  Anything else I should try?

Comment: @AndrewStacey You could answer the question. `;-)` I guess that `tikz-cd` is not going to work, but maybe it does.

Comment: @egreg Ask and ye shall receive ...

Answer (score 1):

I have added the majority of TeXLive to TeX Writer and with that then the following compile:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}
\xymatrix{
A &*+[F]{\sum_{i=n}^m {i^2}} \\
& {\bullet} & D \ar[ul] }
\end{document}
```

and

```
\documentclass[10pt, draft]{amsart}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, matrix}
% With tons of other packages not relevant here I guess
\begin{document}
 % With some text ....
\[ 
\begin{tikzcd}
Y \arrow[dashrightarrow]{d} \arrow{rd} &  \\
Y_{0} \arrow{r}{\pi_{0}} & X \\
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

(Both are examples I got from elsewhere on the site.)

Comment: Already gave +1. ;-)